# Loops FOR and strings

Tags: php

Well I want something like this:

```
    for($i = 1; $i <=50; $i++){
    $string_$i = "hello" . $i;
    }
echo $string_1 . "<br>";
echo $string_2 . "<br>";
echo $string_50;
```

Something like this a loop with strings the result should be like this:

```
1
2
50
```

Thanks everybody!!

Comment: He's trying to use a variable as part of the name of a variable.

Comment: The problem is an normal error of php "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/dominio/proceso.php on line 4" but is answered and solutionated now thanks again!!

Comment: If you used a solution, please accept it.  This will ensure that your questions will be answered quickly in the future.

Comment: Put me that: "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes"

Comment: Ahh, everyone answered too quickly. :)  Yes, there is a time restriction to make sure that people have time to provide alternate answers, so that you don't knee-jerk accept the first hackey answer that kind of works.

Comment: This "forum" is really awesome, i don't know much but i want colaborate :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
   function hello($a){
     return "hello" . $a;
   }
  $string = array_map("hello ", range(1, 50));
   var_dump($arr);

?>
```

then call:

```
echo $string[1] . "<br>";
echo $string[2] . "<br>";
```

etc

**Live Coding Example:**

http://codepad.org/p5T31pua

Answer (score 6):

Why not use an array?

```
for($i = 1; $i <=50; $i++){
     $string[$i] = "hello" . $i;
}
echo $string[1] . "<br>";
echo $string[2] . "<br>";
echo $string[50];
```

Comment: You beat me by two seconds!  Ha!

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
for($i = 1; $i <=50; $i++) {
    $string[$i] = "hello" . $i;
}
echo $string[1] . "<br>";
echo $string[2] . "<br>";
echo $string[50];
```

Answer (score 1):

You ***could*** accomplish what you want with:

```
${"string_$i"} = "hello" . $i;
```

But what you really ***should*** be using is an array:

```
$string[$i] = "hello" . $i;
```

That's easier to work with after your loop.  (Use `echo implode("<br>",$string);` instead of a tiresome concatenation chain.)

Answer (score 0):

You can say `${string_.$i} = "hello" . $i;` if you really must. But it would be much better to avoid this and use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

use arrays

```
for($i = 1; $i <=50; $i++){
    $string[$i] = "hello" . $i;
}
echo $string[1] . "<br>";
echo $string[2] . "<br>";
echo $string[50];
```